# Perforce not respecting the line endings config for a small number of files

Tags: perforce

I've created a workspace (on Windows) and set the line endings parameter to `unix` because I need each and every file to have `LF` line endings.

However, once everything was downloaded and synced, a small number of text files had `CRLF` as line endings. I couldn't find any pattern that would single them out.

There isn't any kind of rule. I have a folder full of `msg_##.txt` with `##` going from `01` to `46`. Every single file had `LF` line endings. Every single file except for `msg_26.txt`, which had `CRLF`. I've also two `.py` files in the same folder, one with `LF`, the other with `CRLF`. The `CRLF` one was quite big at 225KB, but I found no other pattern.

What reasons would there be for P4 to treat some of the files differently?

Answer (score 1):

Perforce assumes all of the files that were committed to the server have `LF` line endings. Because of that, when you choose `unix` as preferred line ending, perforce downloads files as is, since all the files on server have `LF` line endings anyway. The problem is, Perforce does not enforce that every file committed to the server has `LF`.

The files that were causing me problems were probably somehow stored on the server with `CRLF` line endings and that was what I got when I downloaded them.

Comment: This.   If a windows file is saved with "CRLF", and client line ending is "unix",  then the depot file will have CRLF on submit.    Your next sync will get with line endings="unix" will then have CRLF in the file.  Or worse, if you client has windows line ending you'll see CRCRLF.   Consider using client line ending "share" - share will convert CRLF to LF on submit and just use LF on sync.   To clean up the problem files:  sync with LE of "unix", edit the file (dos2unix) to change line edings to just LF, submit.

Comment: You can also fix line-endings by setting LE to "share" and doing sync/reconcile/submit; the "share" causes the CRs to be detected as diffs, and submit will strip them out.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your concern regarding Perforce not adhering to the line endings configuration for certain files. To address this issue effectively, I recommend checking and adjusting the Perforce file type settings for the affected files. Additionally, consider reviewing any client-specific configurations that may be impacting the behavior. If the problem persists, reaching out to Perforce support or consulting their documentation for specific troubleshooting steps could provide further insights into resolving this issue."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).